# Wanted: a way to remove tags from a search

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Click on a tag and you get "N questions tagged TAG1 TAG2....". Could those tag buttons please have an 'x' by them, like the ones on Interesting tags? It's easy to add another tag to your search by clicking another tag button, but not to remove one.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, thanks! Is that a screen-shot of the next release, or just mocked up in a paint program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I've been [fiddling with it](http://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/KENcn/), and made [a mockup](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/126581) of this idea.

[Click here to **install it**](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/126581.user.js) (It's an [*userscript*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), applies to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/))

I'll post a few screenshots so this answer is more colorful and fluffy and upvote-inviting.

> #### Click these "remove tag" buttons to hide all questions with the given tag:
>
> [image: click to hide on summary]

> #### Also works on the tags in the sidebar:
>
> [image: works on sidebar]

> #### Settings are persisted via [`localStorage`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#localStorage)! Clear them with this cute glossy button:
>
> [image: before cleanup]        [image: after cleanup]
> <sub>***Note:** That button/counter is only shown at ([meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions)) [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). To re-enable a single tag, use [inspector](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/resources.html)/[firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127754/124119)/[dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/storage/).*</sub>

It was tested under stable versions of **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Opera**, on **Windows** and on **Linux**.
Wouldn't guess what happens if ran on MSIE (but for that matter, a toaster doesn't run it either...).

Icon made by [Yusuke Kamiyamane](http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/) and [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)'d with [this tool](http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/).
CSS3 style inspired by [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Operafied](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/) with [this thingie](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ee432e+0,c63929+50,b51700+50,891100+100;Opera+version+of+Security.SE+button+gloss).

Also note that this is just a proof of concept (by this I mean that it may not be ideal for daily usage; also, it could fit better to the look of the site and all).

Comment: Belated thanks for this! But it would still be nice as a built-in feature.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, you can remove all tags from your search by pressing "Questions"

Comment: Then it's not a search anymore, though.

Comment: @minitech, true, and I much prefer the proposals listed here. I posted this because I simply had no idea how to clear the filters - all I could see was php posts. If another idiot like me stumbles across this question it might help them out.