# How to deselect a search filter tag

Tags: support, tag-search

When I have a couple of tags selected as a search filter, like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc+ld+linker+c

is there an easy way to deselect only one or some of the tags to obtain this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc+ld+c

other than manually editing the URL?

Comment: Here's the feature request for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/wanted-a-way-to-remove-tags-from-a-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce a search from any search of >2 tags down to only one tag, then clicking on that tag in the right sidebar will change the search to only that tag. Past that, there is no way to quickly subtract only some tag from a multi-tag search short of direct URL manipulation.

Although, if you type a lot faster than you can parse and remove, then you could just retype the shorter query into the search box. That may be faster for some (especially if you're only searching for a small set of short tags).