# When reviewing posts, how to remove the tag-filter?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the review section, I am under the **first questions** tab. I selected one of my favorite tags `asp.net mvc` to see the **first questions** in that tag. So I was able to see one question.

[image: issue]

Now I want to go back to all the **first questions**. So I want to remove the tag-filter `asp.net mvc`.

I do not see any obvious method to do this. I would like to know if there is a way to do this. If not, I would like to suggest implementing a simple `x` button like what we have for **favorite tags**, near the red arrow shown in above image.

[image: fav tags]

Slightly related questions:
[How to deselect a search filter tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63066/how-to-deselect-a-search-filter-tag)
[Wanted: a way to remove tags from a search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40990/wanted-a-way-to-remove-tags-from-a-search)

Comment: One option is to click the [review](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/) link again.

Comment: Yes that works and also we can remove `&tag=asp.net-mvc` from the URL, but I feel that this is definitely a needed feature.

Comment: I agree, its a nice to have. Modifying querystring would be considered a workaround but clicking the link again is a valid option, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&tag=[tag]` part at the end of the URL.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have mentioned this in the comments. Modifying the querystring is unintuitive for not-so-technical users.

Comment: @KishorNanda: Not-so-technical users? On Stack Overflow? :)

Comment: @minitech: Haha, you are correct. But still modifying a querystring should not a way to do something, except when development, isn't it? Any operation exposed through UI would be a lot better, right?

Comment: It might be bad design, but it's still a viable solution.

Comment: I agree that it is a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the [review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/) link again.